# i can see array of objects coming in my http get request from python django but data gets converted into undefined when it comes inside jsx react

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, api, async-await

guys, I have written a rest API a small one in Django rest framework and its working nicely and I am writing its front end in react js but the problem is when I do the get request I can see the values(array of objects) when i console from my API helper file in js and my function which calls the helper file but the data is not accessible or gets converted to undefined, I am writing my code below

```
#my env
REACT_APP_API_URL = http://192.168.43.18:8000/api/
# I know its not needed but I am trying to talk more in context
```

```
// my jsx
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { getAllTodos as getAllTodo } from "./apis/todo-helper";
import TodoSingle from "./parts/TodoSingle";

function HomeTodo() {
  const [todoList, setTodoList] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      const data = getAllTodo();
      setTodoList(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {console.log(typeof todoList, "typeof todoList")}
      {todoList.length > 0 &&
        todoList.map((item, index) => {
          console.log(item, index);
          return <TodoSingle todo={item} />;
        })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default HomeTodo;
```

```
// my helper function or just a function which calls the HTTP method
import { todoAPIs } from "./../../utils/ep";
import { get } from "../../utils/http";

export async function getAllTodos() {
  try {
    const data = await get(`${todoAPIs.home}`);
    console.log(data.json());
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error, "error in get All todos");
  }
}
```

and my function in which I am making the get request

```
// http.js
const HTTP_METHOD = Object.freeze({
  GET: "GET",
  POST: "POST",
  PUT: "PUT",
  DELETE: "DELETE",
});

const BASE_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL;

function genericHeaders() {
  const headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  };

  return headers;
}

export async function get(ep, include = false, headers = genericHeaders()) {
  return makeRequest(ep, HTTP_METHOD.GET, null, include, headers);
}

export async function post(
  ep,
  body,
  include = false,
  headers = genericHeaders()
) {
  return makeRequest(
    ep,
    HTTP_METHOD.POST,
    JSON.stringify(body),
    include,
    headers
  );
}

export async function put(
  ep,
  body,
  include = false,
  headers = genericHeaders()
) {
  return makeRequest(
    ep,
    HTTP_METHOD.PUT,
    JSON.stringify(body),
    include,
    headers
  );
}

export async function del(
  ep,
  body,
  include = false,
  headers = genericHeaders()
) {
  return makeRequest(
    ep,
    HTTP_METHOD.DELETE,
    JSON.stringify(body),
    include,
    headers
  );
}

async function makeRequest(ep, method, body, includeCredentials, headers) {
  const config = {
    method,
    headers,
  };
  // Set configurations.
  if (includeCredentials) config.credentials = "include";
  if (body) config.body = body;

  // console.log(token, 'token')

  try {
    const response = await fetch(BASE_URL + ep, config);
    const data = await response.json();
    console.info(data);
    return data;
    // return Object.assign([], data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(ep, body, error);
    throw error;
  }
}
```

can anyone please see this and tell me where I am doing wrong and I tried to find things on the internet its either totally unrelated or irrelevant or something i cannot understand...
and I don't think it any way duplicate other questions

Comment: `getAllTodos()` is **async** but you are treating it as synchronous in your `useEffect()` calling of it

Answer (score 0):

I made a little changes in your class its not the same code but it can help you.

Basically getAllTodos() async function but you are not using await thats why you cant see your values.

Dont use async in useEffect, make your request call in another function then call it inside useEffect.

Here is your demo.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function HomeTodo() {
  const [todoList, setTodoList] = useState([]);

  const getAllTodos=async()=> {
    try {
      const data = await new Promise(resolve=> resolve([1, 2, 3]));
      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error, 'error in get All todos');
    }
  };

  const loadData =async()=>{
    try {
      const data = await getAllTodos();
      setTodoList(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    loadData();
  }, []);



  return (
    <div>
      {console.log(typeof todoList, 'typeof todoList')}
      {todoList.length > 0 &&
        todoList.map((item, index) => {
          console.log(item, index);
          return <div key ={index + item}todo={item}>{item}</div>;
        })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default HomeTodo;
```